# How to query ICollection<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have two models, where both of them include an `ICollection<T>` object, something like this:

```
public class Business : ApplicationUser
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Request
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I want to query for the businesses and get the businesses whose subcategories match the ones in request (even one match is enough). I have something like this, which I wrote just as a sample, and of course it doesn't work (request is of type Request):

```
foreach (var subcategory in request.Subcategories)
{
    var businesses = db.Users
        .OfType<Business>()
        .Where(b => b.Subcategories
            .Where(s => s.SubcategoryName == subcategory.SubcategoryName));
}
```

So, for example, let's say we have two businesses, from which the first one has Football and Basketball as subcategories and the second one has Basketball and Tennis. Then, let's say our user selects both Football and Tennis subcategories, so my query should return both businesses, because first one includes Football, and the second one includes Tennis.

So, not every single subcategory should match, even one match is enough for accepting the business as a result. How can I achieve it? If you can provide the code I would be glad.

Here is also my subcategory model, in case you need it:

```
public class Subcategory
{
    public int SubcategoryID { get; set; }

    public string SubcategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this running in an ORM or is it Linq2Objects?

Comment: `var businesses = db.Users.OfType<Business>().Where(b => b.Subcategories.Where(s => s.SubcategoryName == subcategory.SubcategoryName));` what do you get as a value for businesses when you step thru the code.. I am guessing that you have not stepped thru the code

Comment: Where returns an enumerable so your first Where is like Where (b=>EnumerableButBoolExpected)

Comment: Don't say "it doesn't work" in your questions.  Always tell us what error message you're getting, or describe the bad behavior specifically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the signatures of your Linq methods.  In particular, [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
Enumerable.Where<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)
```

expects a predicate that returns a boolean value.  `Where` returns a collection, so you can't plug it into a Where clause expecting a Func that returns a boolean; that's not going to work.

What you probably need is something like this:

```
var businesses = db.Users.OfType<Business>()
    .Where(b => b.Subcategories
    .Any(s => s.SubcategoryName == subcategory.SubcategoryName));
```

Notice the use of `Any`.  Any returns a `boolean` value, indicating whether or not a record was found matching your predicate `s => s.SubcategoryName == subcategory.SubcategoryName`

Comment: This works but it still necessitates the use of a foreach loop through request.Subcategories.  It also produces multiple collections of matching businesses - one for each category in request.Subcategories. Is this what is desired? I thought one list of all business with any matches was the desired result. If you use Intersect(), you can get rid of the loop entirely by adding one more clause to your LINQ query, and get a single collection of your results.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
var businesses = db.Users
    .OfType<Business>()
    .Where(b => b.Subcategories.Intersect(request.Subcategories)
    .Any());
```

Breaking this down:

```
b.Subcategories.Intersect(request.Subcategories);
```

Would return a collection of those categories that exist in b.Subcategories and request.Subcategories.

Therefore

```
b.Subcategories.Intersect(request.Subcategories).Any()
```

Would return true if there ARE any categories that exist in both, and false if it doesn't.

And so finally:

```
db.Users.OfType<Business>()
        .Where(b => b.Subcategories.Intersect(request.Subcategories).Any());
```

Would return any business for which the previous statement returns true, that is, any business with subcategories matching the subcategories of the request.